# Expelling father-in-law who commits adultery?

Tags: parents, adultery, hisbah

My father-in-law commits adultery. Is it permitted to kick him out of the house?

Comment: What language is it that you are using? It is not English, nor Arabic nor Persian or Pashto. If you like an answer, you have to speak language, in a way people can understand.

Comment: Questions should be in English. Also we are not a fatwa site and your question lacks relevant details such as who owns the house, you certainly can't remove him from a house that he owns himself. Wives have a right to have separate accommodation\room which is free from the relatives of the husband. The husband must behave appropriately with his father and should admonish him only through the proper means.